# A national accounting calculation

Tags: accounting

The question that I am trying to answer is as follows:

> For a given year, South Africa's Gross Domestic Expenditure (GDE) is R 3 251 414, imports are R 987 781, and exports are R891 562. The table below lists the taxes and subsidies applicable to the South African economy:
>   $$\begin{array} {|l|rr|}
> \hline
> \text{Taxes on production} & \text{R} & 54\ 166 \\
> \hline
> \text{Taxes on products} & \text{R} & 338\ 792 \\
> \hline
> \text{Subsidies on production} & \text{R} & 14\ 358 \\
> \hline
> \text{Subsidies on products} & \text{R} & 18\ 684 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$$
>   The gross value added at factor cost is
>
> A. R 2 795 279
>
> B. R 2 863 543
>
> C. R 2 835 087
>
> D. R 3 155 195
>
> E. R 3 347 633

My Answer is R 2 891 498, because I took the GDE and added subsidies and subtracted taxes. I did that because I assumed that the GDE was given at market prices. I disregarded the information about imports and subsidies because I assumed that GDE was calculated using the equation Y=C+I+G+X-M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I disregarded the information about imports and subsidies because I assumed that GDE was calculated using the equation Y=C+I+G+X-M.

This is where I went wrong. GDE is calculated as C+I+G, but to get GDP at market prices, I need to add nett exports.

Answer (score -1):

Answer is A. R2795279

You take GDE, add Exports, less Imports and get GDP. That is GDP @ market prices.
Then you work backwards, in stead of adding taxes, you deduct them & instead of deducting subsidies you add them.

GDP@ market prices=GDE+X-Z=3251414+891562-987781
                                     =3155195
GDP @ factor cost=GDP @ market prices - taxes + subsidies
                                 =3155195-54166-338792+14358+18684
                                 =2795279